# vb.net xml second run of code does not repeat the same results

Tags: xml, vb.net

here's my code :

```
    Dim xmlDoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument
    Dim parNode As Xml.XmlNode
    Dim newChild As Xml.XmlNode

    xmlDoc.Load(TSProjectProjectLocation.ToString)
    Dim elemList As XmlNodeList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Synopsis")
    Dim i As Integer = elemList.Count

    parNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/S2SProject/Synopsi")
    newChild = xmlDoc.CreateNode(Xml.XmlNodeType.Element, "Synopsis", "")
    parNode.AppendChild(newChild)

    Dim id As XmlElement = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/S2SProject/Synopsi/Synopsis")

    id.SetAttribute("SynopsisID", i)
    id.SetAttribute("SynopsisName", NewSynopsisName)
    id.SetAttribute("SynopsisDateCreated", Now())
    id.SetAttribute("SynopsisDateModified", Now())
    id.SetAttribute("SynopsisRTF", "Synopsis : " & NewSynopsisName)

    parNode.AppendChild(newChild)

    xmlDoc.Save(TSProjectProjectLocation.ToString)
```

this gives me the required result :

```
<Synopsi>
  <Synopsis SynopsisID="0" SynopsisName="TEST 1" SynopsisDateCreated="10/07/2020 15:43:29" SynopsisDateModified="10/07/2020 15:43:29" SynopsisRTF="Synopsis : TEST 1" />
</Synopsi>
```

when I run the code a second time, I would expect to see :

```
  <Synopsi>      
    <Synopsis SynopsisID="0" SynopsisName="TEST 1" SynopsisDateCreated="10/07/2020 15:43:29" SynopsisDateModified="10/07/2020 15:43:29" SynopsisRTF="Synopsis : TEST 1" />
    <Synposis SynopisID="1"...
  </Synopsi>
```

but what I get is :

```
<Synopsi>
  <Synopsis SynopsisID="1" SynopsisName="test 2" SynopsisDateCreated="10/07/2020 15:46:41" SynopsisDateModified="10/07/2020 15:46:41" SynopsisRTF="Synopsis : test 2" />
<Synopsis />
</Synopsi>
```

Why does my code over write the first Synopis?  And why does it do that funny thing with the end tag?

Comment: I think it's because you always select the first node instead of using the node you just appended (newChild). Dim id As XmlElement = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/S2SProject/Synopsi/Synopsis")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to build the children and then add them, I find it makes it more clear what is taking place:

```
Dim xmlDoc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument
Dim parNode As Xml.XmlNode
Dim newChild As Xml.XmlElement

xmlDoc.Load(TSProjectProjectLocation.ToString)
Dim elemList As XmlNodeList = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Synopsis")
Dim i As Integer = elemList.Count

newChild = CType(xmlDoc.CreateNode(Xml.XmlNodeType.Element, "Synopsis", ""), XmlElement)        
newChild.SetAttribute("SynopsisID", i)
newChild.SetAttribute("SynopsisName", NewSynopsisName)
newChild.SetAttribute("SynopsisDateCreated", Now())
newChild.SetAttribute("SynopsisDateModified", Now())
newChild.SetAttribute("SynopsisRTF", "Synopsis : " & NewSynopsisName)

parNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/S2SProject/Synopsi")
parNode.AppendChild(newChild)

xmlDoc.Save(TSProjectProjectLocation.ToString)
```

And credit to Nikki because she did point out the root of your issue was the "id" element logic you had.